# How to get account for IRI/LDEO Climate Data Library

Tags: geospatial

I am trying to download precipitation data from the [IRI/LDEO Climate Data Library](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/) maproom, but they ask for a log in password.

Any idea how to register for this website?

Answer (score 1):

That page has a search box. If you search for *password* you find many links with additional information.

From an [XML file](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/ontologies/AuthorizationRealms.owl) in the search results:

> Datasets are password accessible to anyone who is an IRI staff member, no matter where the person is located (i.e., not restricted to the IRI building)

and:

> User will also need to be [registered at BADC as a data user](http://badc.nerc.ac.uk/reg/user_register_info.html).  The email to BADC support is to request permission to access data via the Data Library rather than from BADC directly.

That makes me wonder if you can get access at all, but it never hurts to try.

It seems that access to datasets is split up and you may need to do several requests.

From their [Technical Q&A](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/dochelp/QA/Technical/passwd.html):

> Maps of climatological wind speed, geopotential, surface height, surface pressure, specific humidity, 2-meter temperature,and zonal and meridional wind are publicly available within the Data Library.
> You will need to contact [ECMWF](http://www.ecmwf.int/) directly to acquire any additional data.

From [Getting permission to access CRU TS3.0](https://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.UEA/.CRU/.TS3p0/.getting_permission.html):

> Distribution of the CRU TS3.0 data set is now handled by the British Atmospheric Data Centre (BADC). To access the TS3.0 data set from BADC, one must register as a data user at BADC (see http://badc.nerc.ac.uk/reg/user_register_info.html).
>
> With the permission of BADC, we have established a mechanism to allow registered users to download TS3.0 data via the IRI Data Library. If you send an email to help@iri.columbia.edu, we can then provide you with password access to the TS3.0 data set in the Data Library.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for the reply. But I already could log in and access data via Gmail log in.
Thanks for you help!